# Works in most cases trying to blur image

Tags: ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create ones around existing ones in a multidimensional array.  It seems to work but creates problems explained below.

```
class Image


  def initialize(pixle)
    @pixle = pixle
  end

  def output_image
    @pixle.each do |row|
      puts row.join("")
    end
  end

  def find_ones
    ones = []
    @pixle.each_with_index do |row, i|
      row.each_with_index do |val, j|
        if val == 1
          ones << [i, j] 
        end
      end
    end 


     ones.each do |i, j|
       @pixle[i][j - 1] = 1 unless j == 0
       @pixle[i][j + 1] = 1 unless j == -1
       @pixle[i - 1][j] = 1 unless i == 0
       @pixle[i + 1][j] = 1 unless i == -1
     end
     output_image   
  end

end

image = Image.new([
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1], #this one adds extra one outside array
  [0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 1] #if last index is 0 it works
])

image.find_ones
```

This code works for most cases, raises an error if one is added to the last index of the last array...also adds an extra 1 if 1 is put on the last index of other arrays.

```
expected result
1101
1011
0001
0011
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in here:

```
   @pixle[i][j + 1] = 1 unless j == -1
   @pixle[i + 1][j] = 1 unless i == -1
```

`i` is the row and `j` is the col where a one is found.
`i` and `j` must be tested against the number of rows and cols of the matrix, to avoid adding an extra point over the boundaries.
If you change to

```
   @pixle[i][j + 1] = 1 unless j == 3
   @pixle[i + 1][j] = 1 unless i == 3
```

It works as expected.
To be more general you should pick the size of the matrix and use it in your statment, for example

```
@rows = pixle.size
@cols = pixle[0].size
```

So, since we need to consider indexes, it could become:

```
@pixle[i][j + 1] = 1 unless j == @cols -1
@pixle[i + 1][j] = 1 unless i == @rows - 1
```